# bootstrap ul container is aligning based on text instead of the bullet

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I have a series of paragraph text content followed by some unordered lists. When using `class="container`" on them it does left alignment with the text instead of the bullet point which leads to the bullet points being awkwardly too far left or in some breakpoints actually being partially cut off at edge of screen.

Is there a correct way or bootstrap idiomatic way to change the styling in this case?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<p class="container">A paragraph.</p>

<ul class="container">
  <li>A list item</li>
  <li>Another list item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. Be sure to tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: I've added a demo of what you describe. Does it accurately show the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `container` class has no business on a paragraph or a list. It's intended as an outer structural element on its own or in conjunction with other [grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/) elements, such as rows and columns.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <p>A paragraph.</p>

  <ul>
    <li>A list item</li>
    <li>Another list item</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I was using a series of containers on a single page since it was otherwise behaving how I wanted it to. Now I see this is not a good design decision.

Comment: You can certainly group your content in multiple containers, just not like that. :)